# Given matrices $A$ and $B$, solve $XA = B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

> Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3&-7\\ 1&-2\end{bmatrix} \qquad \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix} 0&3\\ 1&-5\end{bmatrix}$$ and $X$ be an unknown $2x2$ matrix.
>
> **a.** Find $A^{-1}$
>
> **b.** If $XA = B$, use (a) to find $X$.

I found

$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -2&7\\ -1&3\end{bmatrix}$$

I am stuck on the part **b**. I thought that if $XA=B$, then

$$X=A^{-1}B$$

so I did:

$$ X=
 \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  -2&7\\
  -1&-3
\end{array}
\right]
 \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  0&3\\
  1&-5
\end{array}
\right] $$

and got:

$$X = 
 \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  7&-41\\
  3&-18
\end{array}
\right] $$

I have been told that this is not correct and I missed a technical detail of matrix multiplication. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that we need to make a right multiplication by $A^{-1}$

$$XA=B\implies XAA^{-1}=BA^{-1}\implies X=BA^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @JuanPablo You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your answer lies in the fact that what we actually have is$$XA=B\iff X=BA^{-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help